# Who to contact regarding DBD::Advantage & bugs

Tags: perl, dbi, advantage-database-server

I am in search of who specifically to contact at Sybase regarding Advantage Database Server's DBI driver, specifically DBD::Advantage.

The only reference I can find is to one 'lancesc' in the README, but there are no references to a contact email, CPAN author etc. Inadvertantly I happened upon one StackOverflow user [lancesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10012/lancesc) here.

Would anyone happen to know who to contact regarding this? I do wish this was on CPAN.

I've found a small bug regarding column quoting in the sql parser that they'd likely prefer to be made aware of. There are also several questions I have for them regarding failing functionality.

Much later edit:
For future readers, this bug was fixed using my patch files, although with minor changes in convention (spacing, mostly).

Comment: Have you tried calling Sybase's customer support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an immediate answer to your questions, Sybase's customer support is always the first place to go.  You can also get peer to peer support either on the the Advantage Newsgroup or by posting questions here.

If you post details about your quoting bug I will make sure that it is investigated.

Comment: Customer support unfortunately offered no value in this regard, and even Advantage specific technical support went blank when I mentioned the Perl DBI package. I have however done as they've asked an sent an email containing the dbdimp.c.diff and another question regarding the last_insert_id always returning null.

The bug in question for dbdimp.c is in dbd_db_preparse, and failing to allude to qw/[ ]/ as column quote operators, thus causing failure when a column name contains a ', which unfortunately is out of my control.

Comment: The last_insert_id functionality isn't currently supported.  Per the DBD spec it should always return UNDEF when not supported by the driver.  At the time of last major upgrade of the DBD there was no way to return those values from SQL.  You can now get these values by running the following query.  

SELECT LASTAUTOINC( CONNECTION ) FROM system.iota;  

I will add a feature request for last_insert_id to be implemented.

Comment: I've included the bypassing routine in my DBIx::Class::Storage module for this purpose, which of course only supports AUTOINC type, but at least it functions now. The fact that it wasn't included since the 'last major upgrade' does leave me wondering when that upgrade was, but at least now I can continue moving with the project with a workaround. Thanks for the help, and hopefully quoted columns will also get resolved without an outside path.